# Taking different values for each different id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use only the highest value from a column when there's multiples for each id, but also the lowest from another column when theres multiples:

[image: Current result of my select bellow]

Like in this case we have 2 lines with the same id **11024**, I want the result to only show a single line for each id, but the **dtStart** must be the lowest and the **dtEnd** must be the higher:

(this image was fabricated, just to show how it should be)

[image: Expected result I cannot find]

My select is:

```
    SELECT top 100 
    id ,                    
    min (dtStart    ) dtStart,
    max (dtEnd  ) dtEnd     

    FROM T_registable

    WHERE sup_id = 3356

    GROUP by 
    id, dtStart, dtEnd
```

I tried to use "min"/"max" value, tried union all, tried to use partition by.

Comment: MySQL and SSMS? SQL Server Management Studio is an IDE-like application for SQL Server (as its name suggests); why have you tagged both here? `TOP` implies SQL Server, not MySQL (which uses `LIMIT`).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Why are you using `TOP` here when you have no `ORDER BY`? Why are you grouping by *all* your columns when only `id` isn't aggregated?

Comment: I edited the tags to change mysql to sql-server, because it's clear the OP is using Microsoft SQL Server, not MySQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing dtStart and dtEnd from your GROUP BY clause should solve the issue. TOP is usually used with an ORDER BY.

```
SELECT
    id,
    MIN(dtStart) AS dtStart,
    MAX(dtEnd) AS dtEnd
FROM T_registable
WHERE sup_id = 3356
GROUP BY id
```